# Open a file in an Eclipse editor and set the focus on this editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, focus

I have a strange problem which puzzles me. I open a file in an editor in Eclipse with this code:

```
    final IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow window = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    final IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

    wb.getProgressService().runInUI( window, new IRunnableWithProgress() {

        @Override
        public void run( IProgressMonitor monitor ) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {

            if( null == monitor ) {
                monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
            }

            try {
                monitor.beginTask( "Append to file", 2 );

                ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) IDE.openEditor( page, file );

                monitor.worked( 1 );

                // TODO Bug: Editor is active, it has the focus but doesn't process keypress events :-(
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                throw new InvocationTargetException( e, "Error appending to file " + file );
            } finally {
                monitor.done();
            }
        }
    }, null );
```

I collected the bits and pieces from several sources on the Internet.

The strange problem is that the editor seems to have the focus (the tab is highlighted and I see the blue border around it)

But there is no cursor visible in the editor and when I type something, nothing happens (also nothing happens elsewhere in the workbench).

I also tried `ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) IDE.openEditor( page, file, true );` but with the same result.

When I click on the tab, the cursor appears and I can use the editor. Pressing `F12` has no effect, though.

And ideas?

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? I ask that because I see IDE.openEditor() and not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: 3.7. The code comes from the FAQ: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_a_file_in_the_workspace%3F

Comment: i have solve this question, please Visit :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606181/eclipse-rcp-have-the-same-editor-open-in-editor-window/41631205#41631205

Comment: @ChetanBhagat Why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try `page.activate(editor);` (even though it should already be active).

Comment: The link isn't working. Please updatethe link or provide further information in your answer.

Comment: @Sadik Answer was deleted and no activity by Chetan since June '18. Deleted the link.